# Fullcalendar.io how to add an extra button for specific view

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Can I add an extra button to Fullcalendar header, which will only be shown when the current view is some specific view?

In general, Ii am trying to add a button, which will show only working week, without weekends. I have made two views for WeekView and MonthView without weekends, and i can add buttons which will trigger those views, but I don't want WeekView without the weekends button to be visible while on Monthly view, and vice versa.

Here is my code example:

```
    header: {
        left: 'prev, title ,next',
        center: '',
        right: 'noWeekendsMonth, noWeekendsWeek'
    },

    views: {
        noWeekendsMonth: {
            type: 'month',
            weekends: false,
            buttonText: 'Show work week'
        },

        noWeekendsWeek: {
            type: 'basicWeek',
            weekends: false,
            buttonText: 'Show work week'
        }
    },
```

Comment: you want to set custom view right ? please check this link http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/

Comment: I saw this link, thanks. I have made custom views, but i don't know, how to hide and show buttons in header, depending on current view.

Comment: you need to hide this --  $('.fc-header-right').addClass('hide');  This .fc-header-right shows the button on the calendar at top right do it with jquery in document.ready function